# Sense if USB is alive or dead ++

Tags: power-supply, usb, solenoid

I'm using a 16 channel digital output module (NI 9375) from National Instruments which routes 24v (from a PSU) to several solenoid controlled pneumatic valves. So a valve is open when 24V is sent to the solenoid and off when not. NI 9375 is plugged into the computer through a USB and everything is controlled by LabView. There is a default state of the valves when the instrument is resting, like valve 1,2,5 is open and 3,4 is closed. My problem is that when the USB connection is lost (i.e. computer restart or failure), all the valves closes but I would like to maintain the default state of the valves. I'm not an engineer so I was hoping if someone could direct me towards a solution. I was thinking about if there exist some kind of voltage source switch with a build in something to sense if the USB is alive or dead. If alive, everything is controlled by LabView as normal, if dead, feed 24V directly to the valves I want to have open.

Optimistic regards
Morgan Ganerød

Comment: When the computer restarts, the USB connection is alive, it just doesn't do what you want. The usual solution would be a watch-dog timer.

Comment: How is the 9375 connected?  A CompactRIO or CompactDAQ?

Comment: Hi JDB. Thanks for your reply. Its connected in a cDAQ, NI 9171.

Comment: Talk with the National Instruments people.  There may be an option to do what you want already built into the module.

Answer (score 2):

A simple method would be to add some relays which have both Normally Closed and Normally Opened connections. Wire the solenoids that you want to fail open/off to the normally opened terminals, and the solenoids that you want to fail closed/on to the Normally Closed terminals. This will require some logic changes in your software where the Normally Closed solenoids will have inverse logic control (When the output is ON, the Relay is on, so the solenoid is off).

Comment: Hi Passerby. Yes, great. I will try follow this route. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: This is so lateral I would up vote twice.  The perfect solution if the default state can be kept fixed or only needs rare changes that can be done with wiring.

Comment: @KalleMP all that would be needed is to swap the NC and NO pins on the relay.

Answer (score 0):

If I were trying to construct a device that had a default state, I would want it to function independently of the controller.  That is, if valves 1, 2, and 5 are to be open, then they should be normally open type valves, and if valves 3 and 4 are to be closed, then they should be normally closed type valves.

It sounds like you have normally closed valves throughout right now.

Comment: Hi JDB. Yes, I agree totally. But I'm stuck now with what I have :)